# Errors when trying to install geos 3.3.8 on mac osx

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib-basemap, geos

I'm trying to install basemap so I can tinker with maps through python, but I can't get GEOS to load correctly (prereq for basemap). I run the ./configure, but when I do "sudo make; make install" I get the following error output:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libgeos.la] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
Making install in include
Making install in geos
Making install in algorithm
Making install in locate
make[6]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/include/geos/algorithm/locate" || ../../../.././install-sh -c -d           "/usr/local/include/geos/algorithm/locate"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 IndexedPointInAreaLocator.h PointOnGeometryLocator.h     SimplePointInAreaLocator.h '/usr/local/include/geos/algorithm/locate'
install: /usr/local/include/geos/algorithm/locate/IndexedPointInAreaLocator.h: Permission      denied
make[6]: *** [install-geosHEADERS] Error 71
make[5]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[4]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I've tried updating my XCode terminal commands, redownloading the packages, and updating everything else. Any  ideas on how to get this installed?

Apologies if this is an easy fix; new to python...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key error message is:

`install: /usr/local/include/geos/algorithm/locate/IndexedPointInAreaLocator.h: Permission denied`

By default, on OS X (and most other Unix-y systems), you need administrator privileges to create files in `/usr/local` and its subsdirectories.  Try running the make install with `sudo`:

```
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I've tried using sudo make install but I still get the error message:
    `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [libgeos.la] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
    make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1`

Comment: That's a different problem. Chances are you are mixing 32-bit and 64-bit architectures.  Without more info it's hard to tell.  But do yourself a favor: on OS X, do not try to install complex packages with dependencies from their source or with installers. Instead, use one of the fine third-party open source package managers for OS X. The geos home page has links to the three most widely used ones: Homebrew, MacPorts, and Fink.  Use one of them to install geos and Python and it will take care of getting all the necessary dependencies and building in a compatible way.

Comment: @stensy Glad it helped.  You can help by marking the answer as accepted.  That's the way reputation points are earned here.  If you ask a question, either accept an answer or keep revising your question until you get a good answer.